# Would using Swift's Guard or if Let Keywords take care of not having to use this checkNil function?

Tags: swift, option-type, guard

I understand that programming in a language such as Swift, intent can be expressed in numerous ways.  I'm following a tutorial and saw the code below which isn't what I'm used to seeing because the author created a function to check for nil.  Could the checkNil function be avoided by simply using guard or if let statements or does improve the code somehow?  It's a great tutorial and I'm simply looking to improve my knowledge of interpreting other developer's code to find ways to be more concise myself.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let rideService = DummyRideService()

    private var rides = [Ride]()

    @IBOutlet var from: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var to: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var ridesTableView: UITableView!

    @IBAction func findRouteButtonClicked(){
        let fromText = self.checkNil(from.text as AnyObject?)
        let toText = self.checkNil(to.text as AnyObject?)

    }

    func checkNil(_ string: AnyObject?) -> String {
        return string == nil ? "": string as! String
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways to get rid of the entire `checkNil(_:)` nonsense quickly.

---

#### idea #1

I'd just simply make the outlets optional weak properties then use optional chaining, like:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var from: UITextField?
@IBOutlet private weak var to: UITextField?
```

then you could use this:

```
@IBAction func findRouteButtonClicked() {

    let fromText = from?.text ?? ""
    let toText = to?.text ?? ""
}
```

---

#### idea #2

or if you want to make it more elegant, you could create an extension on `UITextField`, like:

```
extension UITextField {

    var alwaysText: String {
        return self.text ?? ""
    }
}
```

so you could replace the `let` lines with these more readable ones, like

```
@IBAction func findRouteButtonClicked() {

    let fromText = from.alwaysText
    let toText = to.alwaysText
}
```

Comment: You’re missing a var with the to variable. You don’t need to change them from  IUO to apply optional chaining. You’re doing more than the original CheckNil since it wasn’t checking for unconnected outlets.

Comment: thanks the feedback, the missing keyword is added – the `checkNil` method fundamentally shows a wrong approach and presents really bad coding in one go... _any idea_ which offers to delete that method entirely is a way much better one.

Comment: I agree.  I upvoted your answer the moment I saw that you characterized it as *nonsense*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) (under the `optionals` section) to check if the value is nil in this code:

```
let fromText = self.checkNil(from.text as AnyObject?)
```

can be changed to

```
if let fromText = from.text {
    // Run bit of code
}
```

or as you aren't using that value straight away, you can do:

```
let fromText = from.text ?? ""
```

using the [coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) which is equivalent to using that check-for-nil function.

Answer (score 1):

Functions known for usage to gain re usability , he constructs it  once and uses it's code twice inside `findRouteButtonClicked` of course you can use guard or let statements but what if there are many strings to check their nullability in different parts of the VC